# ERROR: Need to specify class name in environment or system property LDAP and JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

This is my code:

```
     public class TestConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "s3cret";
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/dc=userdev,dc=local");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    //env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ username +"cn=users"); // replace with user DN
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=dcmanager,cn=users,dc=userdev,dc=local"); // replace with user DN
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {
       ctx = new InitialDirContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
       // handle
    }
    try {
       SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
       controls.setSearchScope( SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
       ctx.search( "", "(objectclass=person)", controls);
       // no need to process the results
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("catch 1");
       // The base context was not found.
       // Just clean up and exit.
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("catch 2");
        e.printStackTrace();
       // exception handling
    } finally {
       // close ctx or do Java 7 try-with-resources http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
    }

}

    }
```

I got this error (catch 2) : 
*javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial*

I have looked for a lot of solutions, but I don't get the error.
Where is the problem?
Maybe the context, but I think that the code is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to construct the **InitialDirContext** object using the **env** map you have populated.
i.e. use the following code to construct it;

`ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);`

Comment: If I do so, I got the following error about it:
The constructor InitialDirContext(Map<String,String>) is undefined

Comment: Sorry, you will have to use a Hashtable instead of a HashMap.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext.html#InitialDirContext(java.util.Hashtable)

Comment: I almost solved the problem, now I got "NullPointerException".
Can be a problem due a bad typing of the wanted resources?

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: Sorry, the error is in (catch 2):
javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Empty filter; remaining name ''
Because I have empty names.
Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 2):

```
For JBOSS AS
```

create initialContext

```
public static final String PKG_INTERFACE="org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";
public static Context initialContext;
public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
if(initialContext==null){
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG_INTERFACE);
    initialContext=new InitialContext(properties);
}


public static final String PKG_INTERFACE="org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";
check you are passing correct Sring i.e. "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" in PKG_INTERFACE .
```

create a file jboss-ejb-client.properties put it in the root of ejbModule and add ejbModule folder to classpath.
    contents for jboss-ejb-client.properties

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be `ctx = new InitialDirContext(env, null);`, with env being a hashtable.